# printf with pthreads in C

Tags: c, pthreads

I am working with pthreads right now doing the producer/consumer problem. I am currently just trying to get the producer working and using printf statements to see where my issues are. The problem is the code compiles just fine but when I run it, it doesn't do anything but seems to run just fine. I have tried setting my first line to a printf statement but even that does not print. I have tried using fflush as well and I am running out of ideas. My question why would even the first printf statement get skipped?

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void *producer();

pthread_mutex_t lock;
pthread_cond_t done, full, empty;
int buffer[10];
int in = 0, out = 0;
int min = 0, max = 0, numOfItems = 0, total = 0;
double avg;


void *producer() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int n = rand();
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int random = rand();
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        buffer[in++] = random;
        if(in == 10)
        {
            pthread_cond_signal(&full);
            printf("Buffer full");
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
            sleep(1);
        }
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *consumer() {
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    printf("test");
    //Create threads and attribute
    pthread_t ptid, ctid;
    pthread_attr_t attr;

    //Initialize conditions and mutex
    pthread_cond_init(&full, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&empty, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&done, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL);

    //Create joinable state
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
    pthread_create(&ptid, &attr,(void *)producer,NULL);
    pthread_create(&ctid, &attr,(void *)consumer,NULL);


    pthread_join(ptid,NULL);
    pthread_join(ctid,NULL);

    printf("Program Finished!");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: You say the program runs, what does that mean?  Does it run as if in an infinite loop?  Does it immediately exit without error?

Comment: If "it doesn't do anything but seems to run just fine" is your test, I can write many fine programs very easily. :) In other words: you're not being very clear, it's very hard to understand what you mean.

Comment: console output may be line buffered.  Add a `\n` at the end of strings or use `fflush(stdout)` if you're going to debug using `printf`

Comment: if `in != 10` you don't unlock mutex

Comment: I am using a console with linux to compile/run, when I say it runs, it just exits immediately without error. I have added the \n and still the same output.

Comment: Where do you check that the thread creation succeeded? So how do you know it succeeded.  Threads are joinable by default.

Comment: AdrianKrupa's comment suggests a significant error, I would refactor the `for` loop in the `producer` function so that for every `lock` statement there is a corresponding `unlock`.

Answer (score 0):

```
man pthread_mutex_init
```

> `pthread_mutex_init`  initializes  the  mutex  object pointed to by *mutex*
>   according to the mutex attributes specified in *mutexattr*.  If *mutexattr*
>   is `NULL`, default attributes are used instead.
>
> The LinuxThreads implementation supports only one mutex attributes, the
>   *mutex kind*... The kind of a mutex determines whether it can be locked again by
>   a thread that already owns it.   The  default  kind  is  **fast**...
>
> If the mutex is already locked by the calling thread, the  behavior of
>   `pthread_mutex_lock` depends on the kind of the mutex. If the mutex is of
>   the **fast** kind, the calling thread is suspended until the  mutex  is
>   unlocked,  thus  effectively causing the calling thread to deadlock.

That's what happens to your producer: it deadlocks in the call

```
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
```

- except in the unlikely case *n < 2* - thus producing no output.